# How to escape XML null value?

Tags: java, xml, null, escaping

Im having this problem. I Have an XML data but not in .xml format.

I need to display the result based on keyword for search, then it returns the value in xml format. But, there are some nodes that do not contains any value (null value). How do i escape this value ?

I want to display the nodes that only have values (non null nodes). Thanks.

This is my code. Im a beginner in java programming. I need help as much as I can. Thanks all !

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(result));
                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("DOCUMENT");

                // iterate the DOCUMENT                
                out.println("<table border='0'>");
                int index_location=nodes.getLength()+1;
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

                    locations_array+="[";

                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i); 

                    NodeList IDS = element.getElementsByTagName("IDS");
                    Element line = (Element) IDS.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Company ID :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList FULL_NAME = element.getElementsByTagName("FULL_NAME");
                    line = (Element) FULL_NAME.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Company Name :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");
                    locations_array+="'"+getCharacterDataFromElement(line)+"',";

                    NodeList AD_WEIGHT = element.getElementsByTagName("AD_WEIGHT");
                    line = (Element) AD_WEIGHT.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>AD_WEIGHT :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList MAP = element.getElementsByTagName("MAP");
                    line = (Element) MAP.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Longitude and Latitude :</td><td>");

                    if (getCharacterDataFromElement(line)!="No data provided."){
                        String st = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                        String str[] = st.split(":", 2);
                        String latlong;
                        latlong = str[1];
                        out.println(latlong);
                        locations_array+="'"+latlong+"',";
                    }else{
                        out.println("No data provided.");
                        locations_array+="'0,0',";
                    }

                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList STATE = element.getElementsByTagName("STATE");
                    line = (Element) STATE.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>State :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList CITY = element.getElementsByTagName("CITY");
                    line = (Element) CITY.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>City :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList ADDRESS = element.getElementsByTagName("ADDRESS");
                    line = (Element) ADDRESS.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Address :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList PHONE = element.getElementsByTagName("PHONE");
                    line = (Element) PHONE.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Phone No :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList CLASS_DESC = element.getElementsByTagName("CLASS_DESC");
                    line = (Element) CLASS_DESC.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>CLASS_DESC :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList MAIN_CLASS = element.getElementsByTagName("MAIN_CLASS");
                    line = (Element) MAIN_CLASS.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Category :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList URL = element.getElementsByTagName("URL");
                    line = (Element) URL.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Website :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList EMAIL = element.getElementsByTagName("EMAIL");
                    line = (Element) EMAIL.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>Email :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList DISPLAY_AD = element.getElementsByTagName("DISPLAY_AD");
                    line = (Element) DISPLAY_AD.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>DISPLAY_AD :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList ADV_PATH = element.getElementsByTagName("ADV_PATH");
                    line = (Element) ADV_PATH.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>ADV_PATH :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList SORT_NO = element.getElementsByTagName("SORT_NO");
                    line = (Element) SORT_NO.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>SORT_NO :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    NodeList TOTAL_ADDRESS = element.getElementsByTagName("TOTAL_ADDRESS");
                    line = (Element) TOTAL_ADDRESS.item(0);
                    out.println("<tr><td>TOTAL_ADDRESS :</td><td>");
                    out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    out.println("</td></tr>");

                    out.println("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>");

                    index_location--;
                    locations_array+="'"+index_location+"']";
                    //locations_array+=",";                    
                }
                out.println("</table>");
```

This is the sample xml

```
<DOCUMENT>
          <IDS>53850_WP</IDS>
          <FULL_NAME>xxx</FULL_NAME>
          <AD_WEIGHT>60</AD_WEIGHT>
          <MAP>1111:1.12344556,111.67890</MAP>
          <STATE>xxx xxx</STATE>
          <CITY>xxxx</CITY>
          <ADDRESS>123 xxx xxxx xxx</ADDRESS>
          <PHONE>12-12344551</PHONE>
          <CLASS_DESC>Banks</CLASS_DESC>
          <MAIN_CLASS>Banks</MAIN_CLASS>
          <URL>www.qwe.com</URL>
          <EMAIL>qwer@qwe.com</EMAIL>
          <DISPLAY_AD />
          <ADV_PATH />
          <SORT_NO>123</SORT_NO>
          <TOTAL_ADDRESS>123</TOTAL_ADDRESS>
          <INLINE_IMAGE />
          <E_PRODUCT />
          <FIELD1 />
        </DOCUMENT>
```

From the sample, there are null nodes like `<INLINE_IMAGE>`, `<E_PRODUCT>` and `<FIELD1>`. How do i escape this from display in the result page ?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/133242)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to not put any text value for it. For example, if it is an element the value would be `<Element/>`. Notice the open tag closes itself. You can read about the [nillable](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp) element incase you need to build an schema definition (XSD) for it.

Attributes on the other hand don't support nillable type. Personally the way I do it is to not put the attribute at all. In an XPath expression `\\Element[not(@value)]` finds Element that doesn't have a `value` attribute. This allows you to differentiate between null and empty string.

Answer (score 0):

XML does not have the concept of a null, nor how to escape it. It seems to me that you have two options:

1. Omit outputting the tag(s) and content when you encounter a null value
2. Adopt some convention in your XML schema for representing null values.

Comment: XML does have a concept similar to null called nil

Comment: @JamesMohler - `xsi:nil` only works when using [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi%5Fnil) validation. It's not available, for instance, if you use DTDs, and `xsi:nil` doesn't work at all for attributes. Technically, XML Schema is not XML itself and there is no requirement to use XML Schema when using XML.